# Create user with firebase admin sdk that can signIn using email and password

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase admin SDK on cloud functions to create users using

```
  admin.auth().createUser({
email: someEmail,
password: somePassword,
})
```

now I want user to signIn using `signInWithEmailAndPassword('someEmail', 'somePassword')` but I cannot. 
I get the following error

```
{code: "auth/user-not-found", message: "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."}
```

Comment: Are you using the same project on the client and the admin sides? Can you see the user with this email in the Firebase console?

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't seem to be a reason to Stringify/Parse.   This worked after I struggled with an unrelated typo...

**FUNCTION CALL FROM REACT JS BUTTON CLICK**

```
     <Button onClick={() => {
                    var data = {
                        "email": "name@example.com",
                        "emailVerified": true,
                        "phoneNumber": "+15551212",
                        "password": "randomPW",
                        "displayName": "User Name",
                        "disabled": false,
                        "sponsor": "Extra Payload #1 (optional)",
                        "study": "Extra Payload #2 (optional)"
                    };
                    var createUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createUser');
                    createUser( data ).then(function (result) {
                        // Read result of the Cloud Function.
                        console.log(result.data)
                    });
                }}>Create User</Button>
```

And in the index.js in your /functions subdirectory:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// CREATE NEW USER IN FIREBASE BY FUNCTION
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
      email: data.email,
      emailVerified: true,
      password: data.password,
      displayName: data.displayName,
      disabled: false,
    });
    return {
      response: user
    };
} catch (error) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed to create a user');
  }
});
```

[Screen shot of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os7vp.png)

Answer (score 3):

In 2022 there still is no method built into the Admin SDK that would allow to create users in the emulator.

What you **can** do is to use the REST API of the emulator to create users there directly. The API is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password

Provided you have [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) and [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) installed you can use the following code to create users in the emulator.

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'
import httpClientFor from '../lib/http-client/client.js'
const httpClient = httpClientFor('POST')

export const createTestUser = async ({ email = `test-${nanoid(5)}@example.io`, password = nanoid(10), displayName = 'Tony' } = {}) => {
const key = nanoid(31)

const { body: responseBody } = await httpClient(`http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=${key}`, {
    json: {
        email,
        password,
        displayName
    }
})

const responseObject = JSON.parse(responseBody)
const { localId: userId, email: userEmail, idToken, refreshToken } = responseObject

return { userId, userEmail, idToken, refreshToken }
}
```

Please note: As there is no error handling implemented, this snippet is not suitable for production use.

Comment: Stefan. There is a 'CreateUser' method exposed in the 'Auth' / Admin client. Check this out:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: @Mani I agree the method is there. However, the user won't be created in the Emulator, but in the actual Firebase project. Can you confirm that?

That's why I was writing  there's no method "that would allow to create users in the emulator."

Comment: @StefanPfaffel You have to have auth emulator running. Then, the user is created in local auth emulator.

Comment: @StefanPfaffel I was able to get `createUser` to work by setting this ENV variable: `process.env["FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1:9099";` (make sure to set this before calling `initializeApp()`)

Answer (score -1):

Just in case anyone else comes across this I was able to fix it with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006891/firebase-admin-sdk-created-user-shows-up-as-anonymous).

Here is a working example inside of an `onCreate` cloud function:

```js
exports.newProjectLead = functions.firestore
  .document('newProjectForms/{docId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot) => {
    const docId = snapshot.id
    // this is what fixed it the issue
    // stringify the data
    const data = JSON.stringify(snapshot.data())
    // then parse it back to JSON
    const obj = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(obj)
    const email = obj.contactEmail
    console.log(email)
    const password = 'ChangeMe123'
    const response = await admin.auth().createUser({
      email,
      password
    })
    data
    const uid = response.uid

    const dbRef = admin.firestore().collection(`clients`)
    await dbRef.doc(docId).set({
      id: docId,
      ...data,
      uid
    }, {
      merge: true
    })

    console.log('New Client Created')

  })
```