# Firebase admin sdk: created user shows up as anonymous

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to create a user with email and password using firebase admin sdk in firebase cloud function, the user is created but it shows up as anonymous even if I pass email, password, and displayName. I've searched and tried everything I can but the result is same, this is my code.

```
admin.auth().createUser({
email: "email",
password: "password",
displayName: "name"
})
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `.then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
  });`  and console the result and type here please.

Comment: Well, I already have that code but there is no error the user is created successfully and uid is also generated but in firebase console the user is shown as anonymous.

Comment: above double quotes values are needed to be set a correct value. So, the password must be min six characters long, and mail also should be a correct format. Is it ?

Comment: I've try valid email and valid password but still no luck

Comment: Check firebase console, your app have permission for this auth : https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers

Comment: I've enabled email provider already

Comment: @varun FYI, I've just tried your code and the user is created correctly, showing the "email/password" provider in the list of users. Maybe try with a fresh project...

Comment: @RenaudTarnec what is the version of firebase tools you're using to deploy cloud functions

Comment: @varun Firease tools version is 3.18.4, BUT Firebase Functions is version 0.8.0. I didn't have time to update to the new version on my testing dedicated project in which I tried your code.

Comment: I'll create new project and test it there, and I'll get back

Comment: Finally I tried and this the output of userRecord -> user created: {"uid":"Gums2inihjcoCgNX0mL96ujNLlD2","emailVerified":false,"disabled":false,"metadata":{"lastSignInTime":null,"creationTime":"Fri, 27 Apr 2018 15:28:01 GMT"},"tokensValidAfterTime":"Fri, 27 Apr 2018 15:28:01 GMT","providerData":[]}

Comment: It's the same anonymous user

Comment: Finally I found out the problem, the problem wasn't with createUser function but the data we pass to function. I was taking data from a database trigger event object and for some reason event.data were printed in console but when I tried to access the fields inside event.data object it was undefined even though the data was printed in console and it was visible. I fixed it by stringify the event.data and convert it back to JSON with parse function. Don't know what caused the problem but it was nightmare for me.

Comment: @HakanC thanks for your help

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

same problem happened for me and i was unable to login to my application until activating Anonymous sign in in my console of the project so, when you use creatUser() function by default it createUser as anonymous